# golang. Проблема с HandleFunc

Tags: golang

Почему в примере ниже `count++` срабатывает, при посещении роутера `/count`? А `fmt.Fprintf` не срабатывает...

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var count int

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/count", counter)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

func handler(wr http.ResponseWriter, rq *http.Request) {
    count++
    fmt.Fprintf(wr, "URl.Path = %q\n", rq.URL.Path)
}

func counter(wr http.ResponseWriter, rq *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(wr, "Count %d\n", count)
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте поменять местами маршруты: сначала обработка `count`, потом `/`

Comment: У меня всё работает. Более того, ваш код не скомпилируется (лишний импорт). Кроме того, модификация глобальных переменных без синхронизации - это гонка. Исправьте код.